# Downloading from google cloud storage always incorrect hash

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to download some files from google cloud storage (log files from a google play published app).

My code looks like this

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "my-service-account-credential.json", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.Create();

var bucketName = "mybucketname";
var buckets = storageClient.GetBucket(bucketName);
var objects = storageClient.ListObjects(bucketName).ToList();
foreach (var o in objects)
{
    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(o.Name));
        using (var fs = File.Open(o.Name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            await storageClient.DownloadObjectAsync(bucketName, o.Name, fs);                                               
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e.Message.StartsWith("Incorrect hash"))
        {
            continue;
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

The code actually seems to work fine (judging by looking at the actual downloaded file content, it is csv files). But as you can see I have implemented a nasty try catch / hack because every file I download throws an exception stating that the hash is incorrect. I'm assuming the client library compare the hash of the downloaded content with the hash of the bucket and these are not identical resulting it an exception.

The exception is:

```
System.IO.IOException: Incorrect hash: expected 'DXpVGw==' (base64), was '2RMrcw==' (base64)
   at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.<DownloadObjectAsyncImpl>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MyClass.GoogleBucket.Functions.<DownloadGoogleBucketLogs>d__1.MoveNext() in mycode.cs:line 51
```

So my question is how do you download objects, without getting this exception, clearly one is not supposed to do what I have done.

Comment: Can you include the complete exception details please?

Comment: I added the exception details, if that helps you. Note that I tried different times, and many files the exception happens all the time.

Comment: I wonder if it's a bug with the client library. Could you tell me the Content-Type and Content-Encoding of the objects, according to their GCS metadata?

Comment: I think it is the reported crc32 in the header that doesn't actually align with the value calculated by the library.
The files have the following metadata. 
Content-Type text/csv; charset=utf-16le
Content-Encoding gzip

Comment: Sorry for not seeing this before - I've seen it via https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1641. It's probably worth subscribing to that issue as that's where I'll do diagnostics - but I'll add an answer here when I've got one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: Update to 2.1.0 when that's out. (Or fetch and build the source before then if you're desperate.)

This was a tricky one to fix.

The issue is that `HttpClient` was automatically decompressing the data on the fly, but the hash provided by the server was for the compressed content.

We've now made changes to both the REST API support library and the `Google.Cloud.Storage.V1` library to intercept and hash the downloaded data before decompression. The changes are merged in Github, and will be in the 2.1.0 release which I expect to happen in early January.

Note that this won't fix a separate corner case where client-side decompression is disabled, resulting in server-side decompression, but still with a hash of the compressed content. We're [tracking that separately](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1784) but it wouldn't affect the sample code here, as you'd only see it if you created a `StorageService` explicitly, disabled gzip support in the initializer, and then created a `StorageClient` to wrap that service.